# The term for the negative equivalent of a peak point on a graph

Tags: single-word-requests

What is  the negative peak point  called on a graph as below?

[image]

Comment: I think this isn't a suitable question for ELU. The word is ***troughs***.

Comment: He used the word [troughs](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trough?s=t), specifically, Definition 7 of that link.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the dip is a trough, but that describes the overall dip, rather than the lowest point.

Comment: While possibly not directly relevant to the pictured time series (so perhaps not directly an answer to the Q), in some circumstances (e.g if the graph is of a density, density estimate, histogram, stem&leaf plot, dotplot/stripchart, barchart with ordered categories, frequency polygon etc), *antimode* is a possible choice. For example, see the question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87358/multivariate-beta-distribution-no-dirichlet) and a comment [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86051/whats-a-distribution-with-an-abyss-instead-of-a-peak).

Comment: It is the point where, d/dx (f(x)) = 0, there may be multiple

Comment: @Viral - How do you know the graph is differentiable at that point?

Comment: @Dan: The question now is totally different to what is was yesterday (originally OP simply asked ELU to transcribe the relevant word from a video clip).

Comment: A less technical term: *[nadir](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=nadir)*. Literally it is an astronomical term, the "anti-zenith", the point on the celestial sphere directly underneath the observer. Figuratively it is a term for the lowest point of anything.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're looking for **"nadir"**

> - [**nadir**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nadir) - (**noun**) - **the worst or lowest point of something.**

Examples abound :

> - [**"That period was the nadir of his presidency."**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nadir)
> - [**"The stock exchange reached a nadir today."**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=rSwOAQAAMAAJ&q=%22reached+a+nadir%22&dq=%22reached+a+nadir%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCkQ6AEwA2oVChMIws-50Kb_xwIVRguQCh2QSAbU)
> - [**"By 1600 Apalachee had experienced a 17 percent reduction in population size and reached a nadir of 73 percent by the first decade of the 18th century.**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Cjg4LiT2LMQC&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=By+1600+Apalachee+had+experienced+a+17+percent+reduction+in+population+size+and+reached+a+nadir+of+73+percent+by+the+%C2%A4rst+decade+of+the+18th+century&source=bl&ots=JZq_4byFCL&sig=9ppR8XYSgBdQVyCPkjTojjbjHco&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIiuGMs6f_xwIVg0yQCh0-dAad#v=onepage&q=By%201600%20Apalachee%20had%20experienced%20a%2017%20percent%20reduction%20in%20population%20size%20and%20reached%20a%20nadir%20of%2073%20percent%20by%20the%20%C2%A4rst%20decade%20of%20the%2018th%20century&f=false)
> - [**"Public support for the LDP reached a nadir in the 1970s.**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=hwSfAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA53&dq=%22reached+a+nadir%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBmoVChMIws-50Kb_xwIVRguQCh2QSAbU#v=onepage&q=%22reached%20a%20nadir%22&f=false)
> - [**"Thus population growth was quite slow in the 19th century, and the nadir was reached in the first half of the 20th century when France"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_France)
> - [**" With the rise of Napolean, Spanish fortunes reached their nadir.**](https://archive.org/stream/ethnicgroupsclas00cusi/ethnicgroupsclas00cusi_djvu.txt)

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Nadir works. The highest point is the apogee.

Comment: If the downvoter could explain what they think is wrong, it would help me improve the answer.

Answer (score 30):

Mathematically speaking, it is called a [**global/absolute minimum.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima) The smallest value in a set of minima.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. There may be other ways to describe it, but in terms of mathematics, this is simply what it is. Also note as the graph indicates, if it's the bottom of a dip, but not the deepest dip, it is a local minimum.

Comment: Also note that the image is wrong on one count: it should say _global minimum_, not _global minima_ (that would be the case if there were more than one of them there, but there isn't).

Comment: I don't disagree, but I think the OP is asking for a "local minumum" since there is nothing in his/her graph that implies it must be the *global* minimum.

Comment: On the graph "global minima" should be labelled "global minimum" because it is singular.

Comment: In terms of _register_, this is quite wrong. The dual term for "peak point" is not "absolute minimum", is it? "Trough", as suggested by FF, is much more to the point.

Answer (score 18):

There are lots of commonly used words/phrases:

- trough
- valley
- minimum
- low point
- dip
- bottom
- floor
- anti-climax

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, one typically speaks of "peaks" and "valleys".

The other terms mentioned in other answers are not incorrect, but they also are not parallel to the figurative geographic description of the high points as "peaks". Only "valleys" has this appeal.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be called a (negative) peak in some contexts, such as spectroscopy, chromatography (which accounts for most of the hits for "negative peak" on google) and electronics (in peak-to-peak signal amplitudes, one of the peaks is positive, the other negative).